# Order x axis day values in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have below dataset. As you can see I have some quantitative for two weeks and Id like to make a comparison between their days (  i.e: Monday 09 with Monday 10 ):

```
      week       date       day     n
     (chr)     (date)     (chr) (int)
1  Week 09 2016-02-29    Monday  5535
2  Week 09 2016-03-01   Tuesday  7497
3  Week 09 2016-03-02 Wednesday  8658
4  Week 09 2016-03-03  Thursday  6113
5  Week 09 2016-03-04    Friday  4553
6  Week 09 2016-03-05  Saturday     2
7  Week 10 2016-03-07    Monday  5339
8  Week 10 2016-03-08   Tuesday  6196
9  Week 10 2016-03-09 Wednesday  5395
10 Week 10 2016-03-10  Thursday  5633
```

I got below code, but days are unordered.Is there anyway I can order these days in chronological order:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = as.factor(x = day), 
                           y = n, 
                           col = week, 
                           group = week)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: this has been answered several times on SO. try my_data$day <- factor(my_data$day, c("Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"))

Comment: Or if you just really hate typing days, `factor(my_data$day, weekdays(as.Date('1970-01-03') + 1:7))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reorder the levels of the `day`, which is what determines plotting order. You can either type out the days of the week, or use your favorite method for generating a sequence of Sunday to Saturday dates and call `weekdays` (or `format` or `strftime` with `format = %A`) on it. You can either do this on your data.frame before you plot (a good idea, as that's the best way to store the data anyway), or inside of `aes` when you plot:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = factor(day, weekdays(min(my_data$date) + 0:6)), 
                           y = n, 
                           col = week, 
                           group = week)) + 
    geom_line() + geom_point() + xlab('Weekday')
```

[image: plot with nicely ordered weekdays]