# R ggplot2 order x axis Google Analytics API v4

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

How can I order the weekdays at the x axis(Monday-Sunday)? I am taking the date out of GoogleAnalytics with the `googleAnalyticsR` library.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

#Session by Hour of Day and Day of Week Query
df1 <- google_analytics_4(my_id, 
                          date_range = c("2017-07-01", "2017-07-31"),
                          metrics = c("transactions"),
                          dimensions = c("dayOfWeekName","hour"),
                          anti_sample = TRUE)

#Heatmap ggplot2
df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dayOfWeekName, y=hour, fill=transactions)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'white', high = 'green4')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order x axis day values in gggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976244/order-x-axis-day-values-in-gggplot2)

Comment: Try turning the dayOfWeekName into an ordered factor